# quick search or auto-complete in command's history

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to use quick search and/or auto-complete in mini-buffer for command's history?

I will give an example with [sqlplus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlPlus) package but I think it's applicable for many interactive commands.

I can launch `M-sqlplus` and open an sqlplus session by specifying the connect string. The connect string is stored then in a variable `sqlplus-connect-string-history` as you can see from the source of 
sqlplus.

```
(read-string 
 (format "Connect string%s: " 
         (if default-connect-string 
             (format " [default %s]" default-connect-string) ""))
 nil 
 'sqlplus-connect-string-history 
 default-connect-string)
```

I want to run `M-sqlplus` then do a quick search or auto-complete to be able to enter a couple of letters and find the correct connect string.

I know that I can get the previous/next item using `M-p` and `M-n` but I want a quick access to my command's history.

EDIT. I can ask the same question about the `M-dired` command. After invoking the `M-dired` I can use `M-p` and `M-n` to access the dired command history. Now I want the quick search for previously entered directories in dired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `C-r` and `C-s` to i-search your buffer history. I assume you want your history to be stored across sessions, so you also need

```
(savehist-mode 1)
```

Comment: I want to do isearch in mini-buffer for command's history. See also my EDIT.

Comment: So, my answer is corect? `C-r` and `C-s` do i-search in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, indeed it performs a search in the mini-buf.